# Add value in span using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add 500 using onclick function in span 1000
means onclick at check box sapn value will be 1500

JS

```
function add() {
    if (document.Form1.checkbox1.checked == true) {
        // what will code here to sum 500  in to 1000   
    }
}
```

`HTML`

```
<form name="Form1" style="color: green ; font-size: 150%" action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="add()" />500
    <br />
    <span>1000</span>
</form>
```

Comment: first give id or class to that span

Comment: var spnVal = $("#spnId").text() or $("#spnId").val() ;

Comment: var newVal = parseInt(spnVal )+500;

Comment: $("#spnId").text(newVal); or $("#spnId").val(newVal);

Comment: @KushalVora Maybe, OP wants to add the value from the textbox to the span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery, then the the following can be used.

```js
function add(element) {
  var form = document.getElementsByName("Form1")[0];
  var val = form.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
  if (element.checked == true) {
    form.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = parseInt(val) + parseInt(element.value);
  } else {
    form.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = parseInt(val) - parseInt(element.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="Form1" style="color: green ; font-size: 150%" action="#">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="add(this)" value="500" />500
  <br />
  <span>1000</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to add an id to your span element so you can easily target it in javascript. Then target the element and change the innerHTML.

```
var spanToChance = document.getElementById("#spanID");
spanToChange.innerHTML = parseInt(spanToChange.innerHTML) + 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use jquery to bind change event to the checkbox instead of writing inline function calls.
- Use the value attribute for checkbox in-order to provide the value.
- Use parseInt before adding the contents. Otherwise it will take it as string

Example code

```
   $("[name='checkbox1']").change(function () {
        var spanvalue = parseInt($("span").text().trim());
        if (this.checked) {
            spanvalue = spanvalue + parseInt(this.value);
        } else {
            spanvalue = spanvalue - parseInt(this.value);
        }
        $("span").text(spanvalue);
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/92/)

Answer (score 0):

As Kushal has mentioned in their four comments, you need to add an identifying feature to the span so you know where to put the new value.

You can then use `document.getElementById()` (if in javaScript) or `$('#id')` (in jQuery) to access this element and change the text (via innerText/innerHTML in js and .text()/.html() in jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="myspan"> 1000 </span>
```

try this code -

```
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="1500";
```

for modern browser-

```
document.getElementById("myspan").textContent="1500";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the bellow code,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#checkbox1').click(function(){
  var checkboxval = parseInt($(this).val());
  var spanval     = parseInt($('#total').text());
  if(this.checked){
   $('#total').text(checkboxval + spanval);
  }
  
 });
});
</script>
<body>
<form name="Form1" style="color: green ; font-size: 150%" action = "#">

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"  id="checkbox1" value="500"/>500

<br/>

<span id="total">1000</span>

</form>

</body>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Thanks

Comment: but after unchecked it will be 1000 please help